# Not able to use .next and .closest properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why am I not able to change background of `.a` and `.c` classes using `.next()` and `.closest()`?

```js
$(".c").on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest('.a').css('background','red');
})

$(".a").on("click", function() {
  $(this).next('.c').css('background','red');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="a">Change color</button>
  <button class="b">Another Button</button>
  <button class="c">Change color</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button class="a">Change color</button>
  <button class="b">Another Buttor</button>
  <button class="c">Change color</button>
</div>
```

Comment: if you need only one button to be colored - then this is one question, but if you need all buttons of a class colored - this is another. I gave you an answer with working example when the closest button only colored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [jQuery.closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), closest traverses through ancestors and not siblings.

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

Try following. Use **prevAll** and **nextAll**

```js
$(".c").on("click", function() {
  $(this).prevAll('.a').css('background','red');
})

$(".a").on("click", function() {
  $(this).nextAll('.c').css('background','red');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="a">Change color</button>
  <button class="b">Another Button</button>
  <button class="c">Change color</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button class="a">Change color</button>
  <button class="b">Another Buttor</button>
  <button class="c">Change color</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(".c").on("click", function() {   
   $(this).parent('div').find('.a').css('background','red'); 
})

$(".a").on("click", function() {  
   $(this).parent('div').find('.c').css('background','red'); 
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this code would work better:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on("click", '.a', function(){
  $(this).parent().find('.a').css({'background':'red', 'color':'white'});
  console.log("a class clicked");
});

$(document).on("click", '.c', function(){
  $(this).parent().find('.c').css({'background':'blue', 'color':'white'});
  console.log("c class clicked");
});
});
```

See the full working demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sg325497/3/)